# Fragen über Deutschland als Staat: Was ist on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Sind Fragen, die sich nicht auf die deutsche Sprache, sondern auf die Organisation des Staates Deutschland beziehen, on-topic?

Ich denke insbesondere an Fragen, die die Rechtsprechung und Verwaltung des Staates und seiner Institutionen betreffen, z.B.:

- Schulsystem (inkl. Hochschulen)
- Dienstgrade bei Polizei, Militär und ähnlichen Organisationen
- Gesetze und Verordnungen

All diese Angelegenheiten werden in anderen deutschsprachigen Ländern anders gehandhabt als in Deutschland, und stehen daher, soweit ich das sehe, nicht im direktem Zusammenhang mit der deutschen Sprache. Fragen nach der organisatorischen Struktur solcher Inhalte sollten daher, wie ich finde, als off-topic markiert und geschlossen werden.

On-topic sollten nur Fragen sein, die sich um konkrete Bezeichnungen und deren Gebrauch in der deutschen Sprache drehen. (Herkunft oder Bedeutung des Begriffs, Fragen zum Geschlecht, zur Bildung des Plurals usw.)

---

Der konkrete Anlass meiner Anfrage ist diese Frage: [Clarifying the German Academic Ranks](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/37334/1487)

Das System der akademischen Grade ist in Deutschland und Österreich zwar sehr ähnlich, aber keineswegs gleich. In Österreich gibt es z.B. kein [Lizenziat](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lizenziat), in Deutschland und der Schweiz aber sehr wohl.

- Diese Grade sind ein Teil des Hochschulsystems, das von Staat zu Staat unterschiedlich organisiert ist.
- Diese Grade haben gewisse Ähnlichkeiten mit Dienstgraden bei Polizei usw.
- Diese Grade werden von Gesetzen auf nationaler Ebene geregelt.

Somit fällt die Frage nach den akademischen Graden gleich in alle drei Kategorien, die ich oben beispielhaft genannt habe. Soll sie als Off-topic markiert und geschlossen werden?

Answer (score 9):

Wenn für das Verständnis eines deutschen Wortes die Organisationsform wichtig wird, dann ist eine (knappe) Erörterung der Organisation nicht nur *on topic*, sondern hilfreich und notwendig. Im Beispiel wäre das z.B. eine Erörterung darüber, dass es den **Oberassistenten** nur in der Schweiz gibt.

Demgegenüber ist eine Frage allein nach der Organisation *off topic*, wenn nicht auch nach einem Wort gefragt wurde.

Dies angewandt wird im konkreten Fall nach einer Reihe von Begriffen aus der Hochschulhierarchie gefragt, die jeder für sich genommen *on topic* sind.

Allenfalls wegend der Fülle der Begriffe könnte man philosophieren, ob die Frage *too broad* sei. Ich meine aber, man kann schon eine einigermaßen knappe und schöne Antwort verfassen. Also würde ich die Frage durchgehen lassen, wenn ich alleine zu entscheiden hätte.